# Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'temperature_conversion.Program.Celsius(int)'

Tags: c#

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int temp;
            string choice;
            int finalTemp;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a temperature");
            temp = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Convert to Celsius or Fahrenheit?" + "\n" +"Enter c or f");
            choice = Console.ReadLine();

            if (choice == "c")
            {
                Celsius(temp);
            }



            Console.ReadLine();//to keep open

        } //Main End

        public int Celsius(int t)
        {
            int c;
            c = 5 / 9 * (t - 32);
            return c;
        }
    }
```

I know the answer is really simple I just can't seem to figure out what I have done wrong.

I'm trying to pass temp to the Celsius method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `Celsius` method is not Static, like `Main`.

You could resolve this 2 ways.

Make `Celsius` static:

```
public static int Celsius(int t)
```

Create an instance of the `Program` and then call `Celsius`:

```
var program = new Program();   
program.Celsius(temp);
```

Comment: Thanks I knew it was something simple

Answer (score 1):

Mark your method as static:

```
public static int Celsius(int t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) method of your `Celcuis` method. If you want to call a method in the same class with your caller method and if you want to call directly you should use `static` keyword on your method. Like this;

```
static public int Celsius(int t)
{
    int c;
    c = 5 / 9 * (t - 32);
    return c;
}
```

For other option, you can create a class instance and call your method in your if condition. Like this;

```
if ( choice == "c" )
{
   Program p = new Program();
   p.Celsius(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to make the Celsius method static `public static int Celsius(int t)`.
Another, is to create a new instance of `Program` and call `Celsius` on it:

```
new Program().Celsius(temp);
```